# CSS - Display information on 4 side corner outside of an image

Tags: html, css

I have an pointer image that load into a background image, I wish to display some text around the 4 corners of the pointer image.

For example , the pointer image is like this -> [pointer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acRNM.png)

And the code is like this

```
  <section>
    <div id="panzoom" style="text-align: center;">
      <img src="css/dist/img/photo4.jpg" width="2000" height="1320" />
    </div>
    <div id="draggable" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: grey; cursor: move;">
        <div class="count"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

The background image have a jQuery panzoom, and the grey color box is a jQuery draggable. I wish to display the information either inside or outside the grey box around the 4 edges. Something like this [output that I wish to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY7tB.png)

Either display like 1,2,3,4 or 5,6,7,8 is okay to me. But how can I achieved that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you want `<div class="count">` to place in corner.

In that case you want to give `position: relative;` to the parent element (div with id draggable) and `position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;` for top right corner.

Comment: Sorry, I am not so sure what you're trying to say. Can you give some example like jsfiddle or codepen please ?

Comment: Sure here it is https://codepen.io/chelios-the-bashful/pen/VVoNWR.

just if you want to set counter outside of the box use negative values.
Also here is some useful info on positiong https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: hi , how come when I drag my box , my counter won't move with the box ??

Comment: I cannot test that at the moment, try to redefine CSS rules on drop event. Also here is some reference on drag and drop, hope it will be useful! Please share result :D

Comment: Thanks a lot..I think i solved it already...ty for you answer ..it works!